# Event global object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Consider the following code:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" size="40" onkeydown="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
  console.log(event);
}
```

**event** is a global object and is known inside the event handler myFunction. However, Firefox throws an error:**event is not defined** while Chrome and IE output KeyboardEvent {...}. This is one of the most crazy things I have met. Any satisfactory explanation?

Comment: please try this:
` function myFunction(event) {console.log(event);} `

is this work?

Comment: `event` being a global variable is a shitty IE invention that is now deprecated but is supported for backwards-compatibility in various browser. Don't do this. Pass the event object through explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox's KeyboardEvent() expect event passed to the function
Try this

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" size="40" onkeydown="myFunction(event)">

function myFunction(event){
    if(typeof event === 'undefined')
    {
        event = window.event;
    }

console.log(event);

}
```