# Submit button not being sent with request when submitting via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

HTML

```
<form method='POST' id='signup_form'>
    <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
    <input type='email' name='email' /><br /><br />
    <label for='username'>Username:</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='username' /><br /><br />
    <label for='password'>Password:</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='password' /><br /><br />
    <label for='confirmpassword'>Confirm Password:</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='confirmpassword' /><br /><br />
    <input type='submit' name='signup' />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
const signup_form = document.getElementById('signup_form');

signup_form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    let missing_input = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
        if (this.children[i].type !== undefined && this.children[i].type !== 'submit')
            if (this.children[i].value === '') {
                missing_input = true;
                break;
            }
    }

    if (!missing_input)
        this.submit();
});
```

So I'm trying to do some validation in my JavaScript before I submit my form to PHP.  If the user tries to submit the form, I check the inputs to see if they're blank and if any of them are then I don't submit the form.  That functionality works fine, but when the form submits, the `<input type='submit' name='signup' />` doesn't show up in `_POST`.  All the other inputs do.  It was working fine before I implemented the event listener.

This is what `$_POST` looks like after successfully submitting:

```
Array ( [email] => eric@live.ca [username] => ericsartor [password] => asdasdasd [confirmpassword] => asdasdasd)
```

Have I done something incorrectly?  It definitely works fine if I remove the event listener, but I don't understand why that if preventing the submit button from being included in the request...

EDIT:  I found the solution thanks to a link Andre posted.  I posted my own answer, but I can't accept it yet.

Comment: there is no `value` to `submit` which might be why! Try with `<input type='submit' name='signup' value='Submit' />` etc

Comment: I did try adding a value, it didn't make a difference.  In fact, when I remove the event listener and submit the form like normal, PHP assigns a default value of "Submit" to submit elements it seems.  I've been using `if (isset($_POST['signup']))` to check for form submission and that's been working fine without an explicit value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling `event.preventDefault()` at the wrong time.  I've changed my JavaScript to this:

```
const signup_form = document.getElementById('signup_form');

signup_form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    let missing_input = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
        if (this.children[i].type !== undefined && this.children[i].type !== 'submit')
            if (this.children[i].value === '') {
                missing_input = true;
                break;
            }
    }

    if (missing_input)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

I only prevent the default submission if I actually find an issue.  Previously, I was preventing the initial submission every time, and then attempting to re-submit once I validated everything.  Something about this caused the `signup` variable not to get passed into the request.  Props to Andre Rodrigues for posting a link to another question that mentioned this!

Answer (score 2):

I think the easier way it's using: `onsubmit='return validaForm(this)'`

so...

```
<form method='POST' id='signup_form' onsubmit='return validaForm(this)'>
    <label for='email'>E-mail:</label><br />
    <input type='email' name='email' /><br /><br />
    <label for='username'>Username:</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='username' /><br /><br />
    <label for='password'>Password:</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='password' /><br /><br />
    <label for='confirmpassword'>Confirm Password:</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='confirmpassword' /><br /><br />
    <input type='submit' name='signup' />
</form>
```

and

```
    <script>

    var validaForm = function(signup_form) {

        event.preventDefault();

        let missing_input = false;

        for (let i = 0; i < signup_form.children.length; i++) {
            if (signup_form.children[i].type !== undefined && signup_form.children[i].type !== 'submit')
                if (signup_form.children[i].value === '') {
                    missing_input = true;
                    break;
                }
        }

        if (!missing_input) {
            signup_form.submit();
        } else {
            alert('field empty');
        }

    }

    </script>
```

References:

[javascript: validate form before submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918843/javascript-validate-form-before-submit)

[HTML/Javascript: Simple form validation on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134733/html-javascript-simple-form-validation-on-submit)

[get all the elements of a particular form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431162/get-all-the-elements-of-a-particular-form)

Comment: The second link there provided a solution.  I was calling `event.preventDefault()` immediately, then attempting to re-submit the form after validation.  The correct way of doing this was to only call `event.preventDefault()` if I actually detected a problem.  That's fixed it!  Thanks for the references.  I guess I didn't find a solution when googling because I was convinced the event listener was the problem, not the code itself...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it it helps, but you at least need to pass the **event** argument to the callback like this, or else you can't access it :

```
signup_form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {//content})
```

Comment: That's not true in my experience.  If you trigger an event without passing the event in, and then do a `console.log(event)`, it is still available.  I don't know the behind the scenes reason, but it seems that `event` is one of those values that's always available in an event, similar to how `this` is always made available.

Comment: I just found out that firefox blocks the global event (you're using the global event), which is the reason why i always get undefined. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367752/event-global-object-in-firefox)  Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Well there's the issue, I only ever use Chrome...lesson learned, always pass the event in!